# CSS problems with animation? Can't align text in li?

Tags: html, css

This is incredibly frustrating but I am having problems aligning link text within an `li` after adding an animation. I took the animation from a menu that was aligned horizontally instead of vertically and have been able to integrate the animation in however my link text skewed as a result.

Each link is within an `li`. Below is a demo with circle animation:

```css
.menubar {
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
  width: 137px;
  left: -140px;
  top: 38px;
  background-color: #52DBA5;
}
.menubutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Source Sans", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*HERE for menu animations*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}
nav ul li {} nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #52DBA5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  transition: all .3s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #52DBA5;
}
nav.circle ul li a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.circle ul li a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}
nav.circle ul li a:hover:after {
  -webkit-animation: circle 1.2s ease-in forwards;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
/* Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
  }
}
/* Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes circle {
  0% {
    width: 1px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
    height: 5000%;
    width: 5000%;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
.menutext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #39946f;
  font-family: "source sans pro", , Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
  <nav class="circle">
    <ul>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">'.$account['username'].'</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">chat</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">users</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <form class="logoutframe" method="post" id="logout">
    <input class="logout" type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" /></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried placing `padding` and using `left` and `right` on menu button, menu text, `nav ul li a`, everything. Even tried putting text in individual ps within the `li`. 
But my text is still not centered in the box that forms on hover:

[image]

I need the **text** ("username", "chat," etc) **to be left aligned within the** `menubar` **and centered** (the text is slightly to the bottom and very much to the right) within the "circle" box that is formed on hover.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: try adding this to css: `.menubutton,.menutext{margin-left:0;padding-left:0;}` Maybe you can see the difference and add appropriate margins and paddings.

Comment: Btw, i fail to see the need for php tag in this case.

Comment: Didn't work.. any modifications i make move the circle box over too. I included a picture

Comment: Would you suggest trying to work with individual ps within the a href?

Comment: Do you have a live working link, so that i could try experimenting?

Comment: It's a live site.. go http://astrum.xyz/home/ and make an account to get in

Comment: What happens and what would you like to happen? Exactly..

Comment: @skyguy: When the problem is not with PHP it is much better to just post the HTML instead of the PHP code. Also, always try to create a demo because it makes it easier for debugging. You could've possibly avoided those couple of downvotes if you had done this. I've done the changes for you now. If you don't agree with me, please feel free to roll the edit back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I had misunderstood your question and written a different answer. Below is the correct one.

There are a lot of extra/unnecessary settings in your code but the key reason why you are not able to achieve the left align is because the `ul` elements always have a default padding associated with it. It pushes the contents of the list to the right by a large value and hence it will look as though alignment is not proper.

If you make the changes that I've indicated in the below snippet, you'd be able to get what you need.

```css
.menubar {
  position: absolute;
  /*height: calc(100% - 32px);
  width: 137px; ideally these should be large enough to accomodate the element */
  /*left: -140px; commented for demo */
  top: 38px;
  background-color: #52DBA5;
}
.menubutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  /*padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px; not required*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*text-align: center; remove this */
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Source Sans", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 80px; /* add this to vertically center align the text */
}

/*HERE for menu animations*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*text-align: left; not required as this is default */
  padding: 0px; /* add this */
}
nav ul li {} nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-indent: 8px; /* add this to indent just the text without affecting white box */
  padding: 0px; /* change this */
  top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #52DBA5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  transition: all .3s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #52DBA5;
}
nav.circle ul li a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.circle ul li a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}
nav.circle ul li a:hover:after {
  animation: circle 1.2s ease-in forwards; /* changed so others can see animation */
  padding-right: 50px;
}

/* Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
  }
}
/* Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes circle {
  0% {
    width: 1px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
    height: 5000%;
    width: 5000%;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
.menutext {
  width: 100%; /* change this */
  /*height: 20px;
  top: -12px; not required */
  color: #39946f;
  font-family: "source sans pro", , Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*text-align: center; remove this */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
  <nav class="circle">
    <ul>
     
<li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">'.$account['username'].'</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">chat</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menubutton"><a class="menutext" href="#">users</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <form class="logoutframe" method="post" id="logout">
    <input class="logout" type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" /></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion Harry. I implemented what you have above but your code now pushes all the text way to the left.. I need the text left aligned but a little bit of padding between the left side of the box that is formed and the text - your code has the text RIGHT up against the side of the box

Comment: @skyguy Do you mean that you need a small space on the left like in your second image? If yes, that can be done. Please check the update to my answer. I've just changed the `padding` on the `ul`.

Comment: Sorry, no - that's what I ended up with before. I want the BOX (the white box that animates in) to be pressed up against the left. It should span the whole menubar. The TEXT however should have some padding to the left. My problem is Im unable to move the text without moving the box

Comment: @skyguy: Ah, ok I got you now. Check the updated answer. I've added a `text-indent` to the `nav ul li a` so that only the text is indented but not the white box that comes on hover.

Comment: @skyguy: Sorry, not sure why you've suggested an edit which basically removes the entire HTML and makes the answer less useful. If it is just the links (URL) that you are worried about, I will remove them alone.

Comment: Sure, sorry that'd be great

Comment: @skyguy: Done, I've removed the links and replaced them with `#` in both the answer and the question :)